# Weblogic 8.1 to Websphere 8.5 migration

Tags: java, jar, migration, websphere-8, weblogic8.x

I am migrating my project from **Weblogic 8.1** to **IBM Websphere 8.5**.

There are lot of classes being used in java files which refers **weblogic.jar**.

Now as migrating to Websphere, these needs to be replaced or changed and so the code.

So my question is, can i get the exact or similar replacement jar for weblogic.jar. If not, is there any other method to replace the weblogic classes in the java code with websphere classes.

Classes like weblogic.common.T3StartupDef, weblogic.jdbc.oci.Blob,etc are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried websphere migration toolkit - check [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/compmig.html)? If it is well known issue it might suggest websphere workaround.

For websphere related jar - if you have Eclipse, you could download WebSphere Developer Tools plugin and WAS for developers, then point your project to WebSphere runtime, project will  then have WebSphere related jars in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.

Now i have got all the errors as expected.

But how do i find the corresponding similar classes in jars of websphere ?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't have hints there, you have to figure it out by yourself. The best way would be to first look, if there is 'standard' way to do it (e.g. working with blobs). If you use some dedicated weblogic features, then you need to search websphere infocenter, if similar feature exist. You could add to your question classes that are problematic, maybe someone will have good suggestions.